# Ag-Grid-React & React-Testing-library

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-testing-library

I have a custom cellRenderer component named **CellInput.tsx**

```
const CellInput = () => {
  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = useState();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setLocalValue(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
  <input className="input-cell" value={localValue} onChange={handleChange}/>
  )
}
```

This is my ag-grid table **Table.tsx**

```
const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'ABC',
      field: 'abc',
      minWidth: 100,
      cellRendererFramework: CellInput
    
    }
]

<AgGridTable columnData={columnDefs} rowData={rows} />
```

This is my test for the ag-grid where I am just debugging & getting the dom tree.

```
it("should be able to toggle the nif toggle button",async () => {
        const { container, debug } = render(<Table.tsx />);

        await wait(() => debug())
});
```

I observed Ag-grid intermittently adding an extra (span+ copy of cellRenderer) after ag-react-container class. Is this something expected ? As I am not able to see it in the Chrome Browser DOM Tree

Below is the screenshot for the debugged result
[Debug Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUUZW.png)

This is happening randomly which is failing snapshot testing.
Anyone faced similar issue or Is their anything I am missing here?